How to design events and event handlers system using generic in C#?
I want to create an event system in my ASP.NET Core backend using generics for ease of creation and registration of handlers.
The main problem I encountered while trying several solutions was generic conflicts when trying to store retrieve and execute event handlers.
I have a base for the events like this:
internal interface IEvent 
{
    // Required to get with which tag/key event is stored in an external system
    public static abstract string GetEventName();
}

public class TestEvent : IEvent 
{
    public static string GetEventName() => "test_event";
}

And a base for event handlers like this:
public interface IEventHandler 
{
}

public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> : IEventHandler where TEvent : IEvent 
{
    public void HandleEvent(TEvent e);
}

public class TestEventHandler : IEventHandler<TestEvent> 
{
    public void HandleEvent(TestEvent e) 
    {
        // Doing something
    }
}

I want to be able to register event handlers in a service container or somewhere easily, so they would load up automatically. Registering them in some kind of EventHandlerFactory or EventHandlerRegistrator is good too, but that doesn't change the main problem.
I am getting events at runtime from some source, they are deserialized from JSON payload.
So I don't know their exact type.
I can determine their type at runtime with reflection, but this would not suffice since I am in need of high event handling throughput, and reflection (if I'm not mistaken) is slow.
I am also having problems with storing event handlers because their generic types are lost during runtime and casting at runtime with specific events produces null references and other kinds of exceptions.

I am getting events at runtime from some source what is the some source? is it a queue or event stream or just all happen in sync?

@sa-es-ir rabbitmq. Getting content out of there and deserialise it into one of derived classes of IEvent. Deserialisation is ok, I am getting proper derived instances at runtime.

Then please don't create your own pub/sub implementation, I suggest to use Masstransit which has integration with RabbitMQ as well, https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages

@sa-es-ir thank your for your input! I know about MassTransit. I'm interested in how can I achieve what I described in the topic right now. What are my options without using external ready-to-go solutions?

you say reflection is slow but we're talking ms. why are you worrying about optimisation when you're intending to write everything yourself rather than use a tried and tested libraries?

@qujck thank you for your input too! Currently I am using rabbitmq for simple event system and want to do it from scratch for the sake of understanding how can I achieve this with generics.If I don't use reflection much or abuse memory everything should be fine. It's not a rocket science task. Generics and overcoming them is the only issue that I have. Nothing wrong thinking about speed of reflection when trying to create solution by yourself. It's a valid try and not everything should be done with external libraries. Especially without understanding how they work.

"So I don't know their exact type." - is the event deserialized to some concrete event type?

@GuruStron yes! I am using System.Text.Json polymorphism. There is base event.
I actually kind of achieved what I wanted with using actions for registering event handlers. Due to the covariance peculiarity of C# generics, I can't pass my event handler here and there and retain it's event generic argument in method signature (it's lost, casting to TestEventHandler to IEventHandler returns null). So I needed to do everything in 1 method for registering event handler. Looks ugly, dirty, but it works. I hope you guys can suggest something better :D

The basic idea is to use reflection only to build handlers and dictionary from type to handler. Something along these lines (leveraging expression trees):
public static class Helper
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, IEventHandler> Handlers = new()
    {
        {typeof(TestEvent), new TestEventHandler()}
    };
    
    // not an Action<IEvent> due to static abstract member of the interface
    private static Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> HandlerFuncs = new()
    {
        {typeof(TestEvent), CreateHandler<TestEvent>()}
    };

    public static void Handle(IEvent @event) => HandlerFuncs[@event.GetType()](@event);

    private static Action<object> CreateHandler<T>()
    {
        var genericMethod = typeof(Helper)
            .GetMethod(nameof(Helper.HandleGeneric), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(Expression.Call(genericMethod, parameterExpression), parameterExpression);
        return expression.Compile();
    }

    private static void HandleGeneric<T>(object @event) where T : class, IEvent
    {
        var eventHandler = Handlers[typeof(T)] as IEventHandler<T>;
        eventHandler.HandleEvent((T)@event);
    }
}

With call looking like: Helper.Handle(new TestEvent());.
Both Handlers and HandlerFuncs can be build via reflection and/or service provider, I use manually build dictionaries for demonstration purposes only. You also can use some 3rd party library like Scrutor to reduce the amount of reflection needed to be written manually.
This can be relatively easily upgrade to work with DI. For example:
public class HandlerInvoker
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<IServiceProvider, object>> handlerFuncs = new();
    
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public HandlerInvoker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public void HandleEvent(IEvent e)
    {
        var handler = handlerFuncs.GetOrAdd(e.GetType(), CreateHandler);
        handler(_serviceProvider, e);
    }
    
    private static Action<IServiceProvider, object> CreateHandler(Type t)
    {
        var genericMethod = typeof(HandlerInvoker)
            .GetMethod(nameof(HandleGeneric), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .MakeGenericMethod(t);

        var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider));
        var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Action<IServiceProvider, object>>(Expression.Call(genericMethod, p1, p2), p1, p2);
        return expression.Compile();
    }
    
    private static void HandleGeneric<T>(IServiceProvider sp, object @event) where T : class, IEvent
    {
        var eventHandler =sp.GetRequiredService<IEventHandler<T>>();
        eventHandler.HandleEvent((T)@event);
    }
}

And sample usage:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<TestEvent>, TestEventHandler>();
services.AddTransient<HandlerInvoker>();
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var handlerInvoker = sp.GetService<HandlerInvoker>();
handlerInvoker.HandleEvent(new TestEvent());

Depended on the use case the reflection and expression trees can be substituted with source generators.

Compiling expression is FANTASTIC technique I was not even remotely aware of. Wonderful! Thank you!

@idchlife was glad to help! Note that this technique can have some limitations - for example AFAIK it will not work with Native AOT.
